# Is it haram if someone calls me a god?

Tags: shirk

There's a game I like to play and once you reach a certain point in the game you get called a 'god', I want to know if its haram or not because its not me who's saying it but its still me who chose to reach that certain point and get called that. please help me

Comment: Salam and welcome to IslamSE the Q&A site about Islam. To learn more about our site and model consider taking the [tour] and checking our [help]. I suppose such kind of question was already asked on the site.

Answer (score 1):

Being called a "God" is only befitting to the All Mighty Lord Allah, as he is the only One Who possesses the attributes of a God.

Read this from Islamqa for  more information: [Ruling on describing a professional player as “God” or “Godlike”](https://islamqa.info/en/answers/295658/ruling-on-describing-a-professional-player-as-god-or-godlike)