# Comparative religion - Are we not part of God?

Tags: islamic-philosophy, comparative-religions

Adaab

[This interesting question of whether a person can be called God](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/75898/is-it-haram-if-someone-calls-me-a-god), gave rise to another question in my mind.

I have read many times at past that God is one.

But I have read an alternative view that some religions consider God exists everywhere, and within every creatures. In other words, every creature is a part of God.

So what is the Islamic view on this? So far I know that a person can be never considered as a separate God, but can everybody equally be revered as part of God?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

People/Creatures cannot be revered as a part of God. In Islam, God is everywhere by virtue of his omniscience and infinite knowledge but God is not present everywhere in his essence.

> The Qur’an itself states in reference to God that, “He is with them wherever they are” (58:7) and “He is with you wherever you are.” (57:4). There is agreement amongst the exegetes that this refers to the knowledge of God. These verses demonstrate that the Qur’an did use such expressions but their context clearly indicates that this relates to knowledge and not God being present everywhere in His essence. [al-Tabari, Jami al-bayan; al-Razi, Mafatih al-ghayb]

Source: [Is It Disbelief to Say That Allah Is Everywhere or That Allah Is in My Heart?](https://seekersguidance.org/answers/islamic-belief/disbelief-say-allah-everywhere-allah-heart/)

Also, you can read about the discussion about where God exists here: [Does Allah exist in a place? A man in the sky?](https://www.abuaminaelias.com/does-allah-exist-in-a-place/)

Comment: That is really interesting discussion

Answer (score 0):

The idea that there is a single God is called monotheism. Islam is the simplest and pure monotheistic religion.

Muslims believe that there is a single God (Allah or Ishwar). That God has created everything. We are only supposed to pray before that God. Whenever we need help, we call upon God. We do not pray to God indirectly (through any image or idol). When we stand for prayers, we believe that God is listening directly to what we are saying.

The idea that everything is part of God comes from Vedanta School of Sanatan Dharma (or Hinduism). As per this idea, everything in the world is "part" of Brahman (or God). They accept that there is one God. However they find it OK to pray before idol. Since that idol is also part of God. They think it is OK to worship other humans and even ourselves. The ultimate goal is "Mokhsha" - a state where one merges with Brahman and loses his or her sense of identity.

I find some incongruencies in the idea of everything being God. Consider a criminal. For example consider a rapist who rapes someone. God forbid, is a part of God raping another part of God?

Obviously this is not what Hindus would agree with. I am not sure what is the proper response from Hindus to this question. Some of them talk about an "ansh" (part) of God being present inside everyone.

The way I look at it is, everyone is not perfect. To worship a person becomes wrong because of its imperfections. That is why I devote myself to worship of Allah directly.

Comment: Thank you. It is an useful answer.